# Converting image dataUrl to Blob image for AJAX POST with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, binary-image

I have the following code which will take an image, allow the user to crop (with other code not shown or necessary for this question), and then render the image in base64 from canvas.

I need to be able to convert the image to binary, as the API endpoint its being submitted to can't take base64. I have functionality to convert to a Blob, but I'm not sure how to implement it correctly:

```
$(function () {
var fileInput = document.getElementById("file"),
    renderButton = $("#renderButton"),
    submit = $(".submit"),
    imgly = new ImglyKit({
        container: "#container",
        ratio: 1 / 1
    });

// As soon as the user selects a file...
fileInput.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    var file;

    var fileToBlob = event.target.files[0];
    var blob = new Blob([fileToBlob], {
        "type": fileToBlob.type
    });

    // do stuff with blob
    console.log(blob);

    // Find the selected file
    if (event.target.files) {
        file = event.target.files[0];
    } else {
        file = event.target.value;
    }

    // Use FileReader to turn the selected
    // file into a data url. ImglyKit needs
    // a data url or an image

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (file) {
        return function (e) {
            data = e.target.result;

            // Run ImglyKit with the selected file
            try {
                imgly.run(data);
            } catch (e) {
                if (e.name == "NoSupportError") {
                    alert("Your browser does not support canvas.");
                } else if (e.name == "InvalidError") {
                    alert("The given file is not an image");
                }
            }
        };
    })(file);

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});

// As soon as the user clicks the render button...
// Listen for "Render final image" click
renderButton.click(function (event) {
    var dataUrl;


    imgly.renderToDataURL("image/jpeg", {
        size: "1200"
    }, function (err, dataUrl) {
        // `dataUrl` now contains a resized rendered image

        //Convert DataURL to Blob to send over Ajax
        function dataURItoBlob(dataUrl) {
            // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
            var byteString = atob(dataUrl.split(',')[1]);

            // separate out the mime component
            var mimeString = dataUrl.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

            // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            // write the ArrayBuffer to a blob, and you're done
            //var bb = new BlobBuilder();
            //bb.append(ab);
            //return bb.getBlob(mimeString);
            return new Blob([ab], {
                type: 'image/jpeg'
            });
        }


        var blob = dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);
        //console.log("var blob: " + blob);
        //var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);

        var image = $("<img><br>").attr({
            src: dataUrl
        });

        image.appendTo($(".result"))
        $removeButton = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
            .text('Remove ' + imageid.value).appendTo($(".result"))
            .on('click', function () {
              panel.remove();
              $(this).remove();
              return false;
            });


        $submitButton = $('<div class="btn btn-default submit"></div>')
            .text('Submit ' + imageid.value).appendTo($(".result"))
            .on('click', function () {
              var fd = new FormData;
              fd.append('file', blob, 'image.png');
              //console.log("var fd: " + fd);
              var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              var saveImage = encodeURIComponent(dataUrl);
              //console.log("SAVE IMAGE: " + saveImage);
              //console.log(saveImage);
              fd.append("myFile", blob);
              xhr.open('POST', 'http://url.com/rest/v1/utils/guid/encode?' + saveImage + '&imageid=' + imageid.value, true);
              xhr.send(fd);
            });
    });
});
});
```

On Submit, I get the following in the console:

> http://url.com/rest/v1/utils/guid/encode?data%3Aimage%2Fjpeg%3Bbase64%2C%2F…CiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP%2FZ

The current version in **jsFiddle**: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/Lgduvce1/11/)